# SSL configuration on nginx 1.6

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, certificate

I'm tryng to configure nginx 1.6 on a VM to accept https connection.
I have created a self signed certificate [following this tutorial.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-ubuntu-14-04) and then I have added a configuration file like this

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I access the https url from the browser I have no results but this error

```
Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

I think that port 443 is open

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 443
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8603/nginx.conf
```

Moreover, I can wget the index.html:

```
wget -–no-check-certificate  https://<server_url>
```

Now, I suppose that the problem is the untrusted certificate because wget gives error if -–no-check-certificate is omitted but in this case I expect browser (Chrome or Firefox) to give some kind of warning and maybe let me see the untrusted certificate instead of reset connection.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

Firefox gives "200 Connection Established" but no content or warning is shown. It only says that connection has been canceled

Comment: What does the Nginx access log show?

Comment: @SomeDeveloper both access.log and error.log have no info about https connections

Comment: Can you stop the httpd service then restart it with maximal debug logging enabled (exact option name depends on platform)? That might give you some more clues.

Comment: @SomeDeveloper sorry for the late reply. I have already solved. It was sufficent rename .crt certificate in .pem. thank you anyway!

Comment: Downvoting...why?? leave a comment would have been more useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be with the certificate. You can see tutorial to create *.pem certificate instead of *.crt and add as:

```
ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.pem;
```

Comment: thank you! I simply renamed .crt file in .pem. Now I have browser warning as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was on my side renamed my.host.com to localhost and it worked.

> server_name  localhost;