# Nginx configuration for SSL

Tags: linux, ssl, nginx, configuration, centos7

When i try to open my site with ssl i get error ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

There is no information in logs.

Port 443 is open in firewall. On http everything works fine.

CentOS7 (Linux domain.com 3.10.0-123.9.3.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 6 15:06:03 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)

nginx version: nginx/1.6.2

OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

Here is my nginx config file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

  #SSL config
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.key;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_session_timeout 10m;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH EDH+aRSA !RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS";
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_stapling on;
  resolver 8.8.8.8;
  ssl_stapling_verify on;

  root /home/main/www;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.com-access.log main buffer=16k;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/domain.com-dev-error.log warn;

  location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
  }

  location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location ~ /\.          { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }
  location ~ ~$           { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }

  location ~* .(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|xml|swf|flv|eot|ttf|woff|pdf|xls|htc|html|unity3d)$ {
  add_header Pragma "public";
  add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
     access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
      expires   360d;
  }

  location ~ /.ht {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
         log_not_found off;
 }

  location ~* \.php$ {
        #rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
  }

  location / {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
  }
}
```

Telnet results:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ telnet domain.com 80
Trying 123.45.67.89...
Connected to domain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Thu, 18 Dec 2014 13:13:20 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 172
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.6.2</center>
</body>
</html>
Connection closed by foreign host.
[user@localhost ~]$ telnet domain.com 443
Trying 123.45.67.89...
Connected to domain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Problem was solved. I find in Global config file line:

```
server { listen 443 ssl; server_name _; access_log off; error_log off; return 444; }
```

After removing it, all works fine.

Comment: please show output of `netstat -tulpen|grep 443` to make sure nginx is actually listening on port 443. Alos, are there errors in the error_log?

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          17055261   29781/nginx: master

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved. I find in Global config file line:

```
server { listen 443 ssl; server_name _; access_log off; error_log off; return 444; }
```

After removing it, all works fine.

– Guliy Boris

Answer (score 0):

listen 433 ssl is correct in this setup.  It allows the regular and ssl definitions to be in the same block but tells nginx to only enable ssl on the port 443 requests.

The problem is possibly with your cert file.  Check this question on the same issue [SSL configuration on nginx 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497996/ssl-configuration-on-nginx-1-6)

Answer (score -1):

"Listen 443 ssl"  looks redundant. you should put "Listen 443" (and keep the "ssl on" later on the config)

Comment: [This is no longer the case](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html): "Prior to 0.7.14 SSL could not be enabled selectively for individual listening sockets, as shown above. SSL could only be enabled for the entire server using the ssl directive, making it impossible to set up a single HTTP/HTTPS server. The ssl parameter of the listen directive was added to solve this issue. The use of the ssl directive in modern versions is thus discouraged."