# PHP file upload size limits

Tags: php, apache, file-upload

I know this question has been asked before, but I've gone through all previously described options and I'm wondering if I'm missing an option. I'm trying upload a file through Apache/PHP that is greater than 2.000GB in size. Files smaller than that work fine.

The following php.ini variables are set, and I have restarted Apache to make sure they are in effect:

```
max_input_vars = 10000
post_max_size = 5000M
upload_max_filesize = 5000M
max_file_uploads = 1000
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 600
memory_limit = 10000M
```

I am using a javascript uploader, with no filesize limits in the script, and a PHP page to receive the uploaded files, also with no limits in the script. When it fails, it only gives this error message in the javascript console in Chrome and IE: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`. There are file size limit checks in the javascript and PHP pages, but those errors are never displayed... so I'm thinking it is not even getting the chance to check the file size in either place.

Comment: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET means that you have some misconfiguration in apache/nginx settings
You might have look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497996/ssl-configuration-on-nginx-1-6

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone hits this 2.0GB limit, the fix for me was that PHP 5.4 did not support uploads greater than 2.0GB. This limit was changed in PHP 5.6: http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.6.0

Upgrading to PHP 7.0 worked for me!